# How do you fix this "unlabeled value" error?

Tags: ltspice

[image]

First time using LT spice, just trying to finish this experiment but it's not running. Any possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 4):

The `bi` symbol is for a behavioral current source, which requires the value to be entered as an expression in the form of `I=<expression>`.  In your case it would be `I=60m` or `I=20m`.

[image]

But since you are using a constant value, you should simply use a constant current source which is listed under `current` in the "Select Component Symbol" window.

[image]

Using that symbol, you would enter the constant values the same way as you previously tried to do with the `bi` source.  Example below:

[image]